# Eclipse + PyDev ImportError

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev, gensim

I am having trouble getting **PyDev on Eclipse** to recognize installed modules (**gensim**), which work fine in IDLE. I am using Windows Vista, 32-bit. Python 2.7.

I have found this question asked: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070423/adding-python-modules-to-pydev-in-eclipse-results-in-import-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590435/eclipse-pydev-eclipse-telling-me-that-this-is-an-invalid-import), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983088/unresolved-import-models).

The recommended solution is to go to **preferences > pydev > interpreter - python**, and remove and re-add (w/ Auto Config) the python interpreter. I have done this, and have restarted Eclipse. In `PYTHONPATH`, `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.0-py2.7.egg`, appears, but I still run into the import error. My code is:

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
```

And this yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jpan\Documents\workspace\FirstProject\src\gensim.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
  File "C:\Users\Jpan\Documents\workspace\FirstProject\src\gensim.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
ImportError: cannot import name corpora
```

Another recommended solution is to manually add the folder by clicking "New Folder" in the bottom part of the interpreter - python screen and navigating to the location where gensim installed. I have also done this, and added `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.0-py2.7.egg\gensim`, which has all the necessary `\__init__.py` files. But, I still get the `ImportError`.

Any suggestions for what else I could try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is independent of Eclipse/PyDev. You'll get the same error running the code in any other way. Your module imports `gensim`. The first entry on the `PYTHONPATH` is the current directory, and your module is called `gensim.py`, so your module attempts to import iteself. Because imports are cached, you don't get into infinite recursion but get a reference to a module containing... nothing, especially not the things you expected from the "real" `gensim` module.

The error message should mention this possibility, it's incredibly common. The solution is to rename your file.