# Force eclipse to reload Python modules

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, setuptools

I have started a Eclipse PyDev project, and found out that [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) was missing.

I installed it using `easy_install`, and now the scripts runs fine from the command line. Eclipse, however, still thinks that [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) isn't installed, displaying an annoying error message and not supplying any introspection or auto complete.

How can I force Eclipse to reload the system's python package list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reconfigure the python interpreters. Normally the automatic configuration utility should discover everything by itself, but otherwise you can manually add/remove packages. Here's a screenshot of where the settings are located:

[image]

In the only occasion in which I can recall I needed to do that, all I did was to remove the python interpreter from the list and running the Auto Config procedure again, but it should also be possible to simply add a library (bottom half of the screenshot).

HTH!

Comment: I had to delete the `import` line, and re-write it, but it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Note: if you add a package to some directory that's already there, just pressing 'apply' will show a list of which directories should be rescanned.